# The error about “dropDatabase fail: chunk is not in COMPLETE state”

Tags: database, dolphindb

I run the following code in python:

```py
exchange_path = f"dfs://market/{exchange.value}"
script = f'''if(existsDatabase(\"{exchange_path}\")) {{ dropDatabase(\"{exchange_path}\") }}'''
session.run(script)
```

There is an error:

```py
RuntimeError: <Server Exception> in run: dropDatabase("dfs://market/BINANCE") => deleteSubChunks failed on '/market/BINANCE', chunk 17a19f25-cc16-15ae-714b-5ee30d5d6795 is not in COMPLETE state
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly drop the partitions by dropPartition and then use dropDatabase to delete the database.

```py
dbName=exchange_path 
fileCond=dbName + "%"
t=exec substr(file,strlen(dbName)) from rpc(getControllerAlias(),getClusterChunksStatus) where file like fileCond, state != "COMPLETE"
dropPartition(database("dfs:/"+dbName),t,,true)
```